# Search Focus and Out

Tags: html, css

So I was making an search bar and I was wondering how would I make I so when you click in the search bar it shows an different image and when you click out it goes to the old image

**CSS**

```
/***** search form *****/
#search-form {
    padding:45px 10px 0 0;
    float:right;
}
#search-form fieldset {
    position:relative; 
    width:100%; 
    display:block; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
#search-form .search-field {
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    height:34px;
    background:url(../images/search-bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; 
}
#search-form input {
    width:245px; 
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:1.25em;
    padding:9px 15px 9px; 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:none;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    outline:none;
}
#search-form .search-button {
    display:block; 
    width:20px;
    height:21px;
    text-indent:-5000px;
    background:url(../images/search-icon.png) left top no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    right:7px;
    top:7px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="search-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="search-field">
         <input name="search" id="searchFieldBox" type="text" value="" onfocus="fieldSwap('search-bg2.png')" >
         <a class="search-button" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit()"></a>   
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now what would I have to edit to make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay OP, I cleared some previous declarations in your CSS to not interfere with the added CSS, here are the declarations I removed:

```
#search-form input {background: none} and 
#search-form .search-field  {
   background:url(../images/search-bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; 
}
```

Here is the updated jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/WXJGy/